# Best way to package a series of commands that will be reused throughout your program?

Tags: c#

I have several different instances in my code where I find myself copying/pasting blocks of code that get reused in other areas of my application. I'm relatively new to C# and am unsure of how to package this information in a way that is more convenient and safer for reuse. Any way I can assign this block to some sort of function/class so that all I have to do is call the function/class name to run this series of commands?

```
//Clear all form entries.
comboBoxAccount.ResetText();
comboBoxAccount.SelectedIndex = -1;
textBoxAccountName.Clear();
comboBoxPrinter.ResetText();
comboBoxPrinter.SelectedIndex = -1;
comboBoxCheckType.ResetText();
comboBoxCheckType.SelectedIndex = -1;
textBoxCheckNumber.Clear();
textBoxRoutingNumber.Clear();
textBoxAccountNumber.Clear();
textBoxMicrFormat.Clear();
textBoxAccountAddress.Clear();
textBoxBankAddress.Clear();
```

Comment: Are you always applying the actions to those controls or different ones? Why can't you just wrap that code in a function call?

Comment: [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)

Comment: looks like a reset function to me.

Comment: Perhaps read an article on "DRY" design pattern (Don't Repeat Yourself). First google result: https://dotnetcodr.com/2013/10/17/the-dont-repeat-yourself-dry-design-principle-in-net-part-1/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can create a  public `Static` class or a public class with a `Static` method
ResetControls and call it whatever number of times you want. This method efficient when you want to do the reset from different classes(modules).

However, If you need to call that piece of code from code behind of a form then above method is overkill. Just create a private function and call it.

```
 private void reset()
{
comboBoxAccount.ResetText();
comboBoxAccount.SelectedIndex = -1;
textBoxAccountName.Clear();
comboBoxPrinter.ResetText();
comboBoxPrinter.SelectedIndex = -1;
comboBoxCheckType.ResetText();
comboBoxCheckType.SelectedIndex = -1;
textBoxCheckNumber.Clear();
textBoxRoutingNumber.Clear();
textBoxAccountNumber.Clear();
textBoxMicrFormat.Clear();
textBoxAccountAddress.Clear();
textBoxBankAddress.Clear();
}
```

Comment: A static method would need access to the instance controls which would be quite clunky.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for. I was trying to do this through a class at first but it just didn't feel like the right solution. I know about functions but have not had to use them in C# until now. Seeing it helps connect the dots.